# Database encryption for a desktop app - possible without password?

Tags: database, actionscript-3, encryption

I'm coding an AS3 AIR app that has an SQLite database. I'd like to encrypt the database so that the user can feel comfortable saving sensitive information in it ie if a hacker gains access to the user's database file remotely, they won't be able to load it into their own copy of the app to read the data. However, I don't want to make the user enter a password each time they use the app.

Is this possible, or is password authentication the only way please?

Answer (score 1):

Encryption of database and access on platform are two different issues.

**About access:**

Your app can have a system to remeber, after you have installed, so you don't put anytime your password, because it know you.

**About encryption:**

You can encrypt your data with a secure algorithm, so you don't show in your table the real content but encrypted content. So when you show in your app the content, you must implement a decodifier of your data.